# How to specify the split ratio for VSplit or HSplit in TraisUI?

Tags: python, traitsui

My view is defined as below

```
DefaultView = View(
    HSplit(
        Item("figure", editor=MPLFigureEditor(toolbar=True),
             show_label=False),
        VGroup(
            Item("draw_button", show_label=False)),
        show_labels=False
    ),
    width=800, height=600, title="Facial Triangles", resizable=True)
```

I've look up the official document of [HSplit](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ETS3_API/enthought.traits.ui.group.HSplit.html) and found there is none attribute or method to specify the initial split ratio.

Is there a method to specify the initial split ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this discussion](http://enthought-dev.117412.n3.nabble.com/Specifying-the-default-split-ratio-for-vsplit-and-hsplit-td3583032.html), I've gotten the method: by specify the `width` or `height` attribute of the `Item`. For example, my above view is updated:

```
DefaultView = View(
    HSplit(
        Item("figure", editor=MPLFigureEditor(toolbar=True), width=0.95,
             show_label=False),
        VGroup(
            Item("draw_button", show_label=False)),
        show_labels=False
    ),
    width=800, height=600, title="Facial Triangles", resizable=True)
```